# Entropy and Information Gain

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, information-theory

Simple question I hope.

If I have a set of data like this:

```
Classification  attribute-1  attribute-2

Correct         dog          dog 
Correct         dog          dog
Wrong           dog          cat 
Correct         cat          cat
Wrong           cat          dog
Wrong           cat          dog
```

Then what is the information gain of attribute-2 relative to attribute-1?

I've computed the entropy of the whole data set: -(3/6)log2(3/6)-(3/6)log2(3/6)=1

Then I'm stuck!  I think you need to calculate entropies of attribute-1 and attribute-2 too?  Then use these three calculations in an information gain calculation?

Any help would be great,

Thank you :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well first you have to calculate the entropy for each of the attributes. After that you calculate the information gain. Just give me a moment and I'll show how it should be done.

for attribute-1

```
attr-1=dog:
info([2c,1w])=entropy(2/3,1/3)

attr-1=cat
info([1c,2w])=entropy(1/3,2/3)
```

Value for attribute-1:

```
info([2c,1w],[1c,2w])=(3/6)*info([2c,1w])+(3/6)*info([1c,2w])
```

Gain for attribute-1:

```
gain("attr-1")=info[3c,3w]-info([2c,1w],[1c,2w])
```

And you have to do the same for the next attribute.