# shape of input to calculate information gain

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, feature-selection, entropy

I want to calculate the `information gain` on `20_newsgroup` data set.

I am using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752650/information-gain-calculation-with-scikit-learn)(also I put a copy of the code down of the question).

As you see the input to the algorithm is `X,y`
My confusion is that, `X` is going to be a `matrix` with `documents` in rows and `features as column`. (according to 20_newsgroup it is 11314,1000 
 in case i only considered 1000 features).

but according to the concept of information gain, it should calculate information gain for `each feature.`

(So I was expecting to see the code in a way loop through each feature, so the input to the function be a matrix where rows are features and columns are class)

But X is not feature here but X stands for documents, and I can not see the part in the code that take care of this part! ( I mean considering each document, and then going through each feature of that document; like looping through rows but at the same time looping through columns as the features are stored in columns).

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465447/entropy-and-information-gain) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241525/python-information-gain-implementation) and many similar questions but they are not clear in terms of input matrix shape.

this is the code for reading 20_newsgroup:

```
newsgroup_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
X,y = newsgroup_train.data,newsgroup_train.target

cv = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.99,min_df=0.001, max_features=1000,stop_words='english',lowercase=True,analyzer='word')
X_vec = cv.fit_transform(X)
```

`(X_vec.shape)` is (11314,1000) which is not features in the 20_newsgroup data set. I am thinking am I calculating Information gain in a incorrect way?

This is the code for `Information gain`:

```
def information_gain(X, y):

    def _calIg():
        entropy_x_set = 0
        entropy_x_not_set = 0
        for c in classCnt:
            probs = classCnt[c] / float(featureTot)
            entropy_x_set = entropy_x_set - probs * np.log(probs)
            probs = (classTotCnt[c] - classCnt[c]) / float(tot - featureTot)
            entropy_x_not_set = entropy_x_not_set - probs * np.log(probs)
        for c in classTotCnt:
            if c not in classCnt:
                probs = classTotCnt[c] / float(tot - featureTot)
                entropy_x_not_set = entropy_x_not_set - probs * np.log(probs)
        return entropy_before - ((featureTot / float(tot)) * entropy_x_set
                             +  ((tot - featureTot) / float(tot)) * entropy_x_not_set)

    tot = X.shape[0]
    classTotCnt = {}
    entropy_before = 0
    for i in y:
        if i not in classTotCnt:
            classTotCnt[i] = 1
        else:
            classTotCnt[i] = classTotCnt[i] + 1
    for c in classTotCnt:
        probs = classTotCnt[c] / float(tot)
        entropy_before = entropy_before - probs * np.log(probs)

    nz = X.T.nonzero()
    pre = 0
    classCnt = {}
    featureTot = 0
    information_gain = []
    for i in range(0, len(nz[0])):
        if (i != 0 and nz[0][i] != pre):
            for notappear in range(pre+1, nz[0][i]):
                information_gain.append(0)
            ig = _calIg()
            information_gain.append(ig)
            pre = nz[0][i]
            classCnt = {}
            featureTot = 0
        featureTot = featureTot + 1
        yclass = y[nz[1][i]]
        if yclass not in classCnt:
            classCnt[yclass] = 1
        else:
            classCnt[yclass] = classCnt[yclass] + 1
    ig = _calIg()
    information_gain.append(ig)

    return np.asarray(information_gain)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after going through the code in detail, I learned more about `X.T.nonzero()`.

Actually it is correct that information gain needs to loop through features.
Also it is correct that the matrix `scikit-learn` give us here is based on `doc-features`.

But:

in code it uses `X.T.nonzero()` which technically transform all the nonzero values into array. and then in the next row loop through the length of that array range(0, `len(X.T.nonzero()[0])`.

Overall, this part X.T.nonzero()[0] is returning all the none zero features to us :)